# Using -ndesu correctly?

Tags: learning

Does this translate correctly?

First, let me go to the washroom.

まず、おてあらいにいきたいんです。

Comment: I've heard "その前に" used instead of "まず" in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It is literary translated as "まず、お手洗いに行かせて(ください)" and "まず、お手洗いにいきたいんです" is translated as "First, I want to go to the washroom". However it is probably understood as "まず、お手洗いに行かせて(ください)" when you said to someone.

If you want to make clear the demand, you can say "まず、お手洗いに行きたいんですけど、いいですか?".